# How to use clickonce for html button

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, html

I am trying to use this javascript for clcik once but I m unable to get results
can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this script

```
function clickOnce(btn, msg) {
// Test if we are doing a validation
//if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
    // if we are doing a validation, return if it's false
    //if (Page_ClientValidate() == false) { return false; }
//}

// Ensure that the button is not of type "submit"
if (btn.getAttribute('type') == 'button') {
    // The msg attibute is absolutely optional
    // msg will be the text of the button while it's disabled
    if (!msg || (msg = 'undefined')) { msg = 'Loading...'; }

    btn.value = msg;

    // The magic :D
    btn.disabled = true;
}

return true;
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this script

Answer (score 2):

Your second `if` clause does not check if `msg` is `undefined`, but *assigns* `undefined` to it. Therefore, the final value of `msg` will always be `Loading...`.

Also, `null` and `undefined` are already taken care of by the `!` operator, so you only need:

```
if (!msg) {
    msg = "Loading...";
}
btn.value = msg;
```

Or maybe, if you want to take advantage of the short-circuiting nature of the `||` operator:

```
btn.value = msg || "Loading...";
```

Comment: This is not working as I want.
I m trying to firing a Action in mvc and condition that runs is based on which button is clicked when I m using this script I m getting Loading message but the condition is all passed so I thought to add ajax to it 
I want it to enter that condition as well whicih is more important for me

Answer (score 1):

have you debugged this with developer tools in the browser?  it acts as though the function is not finishing its process like you think it is, so the return true is never hit, and there is an error being thrown somewhere.

Comment: I m unable to trace the error is there any other javascript so that I can show Please wait message in my button with button disabled

Comment: You can always throw in some alerts to see what values are held for 'msg' and 'btn' ...  if these are undefined then the code will error out and not do anything.  how are you debugging the javascript?